# How/Can I install/run Windows on my older iMac (2007) running OS 10.95?

Tags: bootcamp, imac, windows

I was just told by someone that i won't be able to install Bootcamp to run Windows on my iMac (2007) - it's been upgraded/rebuilt at least once and upgraded again less than 6 mos ago. Is there another option, or were they wrong (just saw a thread about someone installing Bootcamp on a 2001 iMac.

Answer (score 1):

It **MAY** be possible to install Windows 7 on this Mac, possibly Vista, nothing later though. Understand that Windows 7 is EOL in January of 2020. So using it would be a bad idea if you need to connect to the internet with it.

You'll need an ISO (disk Image) of the Windows OS and the correct Bootcamp software (V 4 - 5) and you may be able to get this up and running. there is an archived Apple KBase artical about this [here.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016)